# How do I query for dollar amounts that have too much precision?

Tags: sql, sql-server, precision, modulo

I've got the following table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [items] (
    [qty] INT NOT NULL,
    [price] MONEY NOT NULL,
    [subtotal] MONEY NOT NULL,
    ...
);
```

Some of the rows look like this:

```
+--------+-------+----------+
| qty    | price | subtotal |
+--------+-------+----------+
| 100000 | 0.017 | 1700.00  |
+--------+-------+----------+
```

I don't like fractional cents and this data isn't that important, so I want to adjust any rows that have fractional-cent prices. So I'd change the example row above to look like this instead:

```
+-----+---------+----------+
| qty | price   | subtotal |
+-----+---------+----------+
| 1   | 1700.00 | 1700.00  |
+-----+---------+----------+
```

If I used this query:

```
SELECT * FROM [items]
WHERE ([price] * 1000) % 10 > 0
```

...that would get me all the rows where the price goes out to precision 3. And that's useful for this example where the price is 1.7¢. But what if it's something like 0.002¢ (i.e. precision 5)? Do I need to write a query with a bunch of OR statements for each precision I think it might be, or is there a simpler way to say `WHERE [price] (has precision ≥ 3)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [`round`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx) the price to two decimal places, and then compare it to the original value:

```
WHERE ROUND([price], 2) <> [price]
```